# Why are the tails of distributions estimated from samples most prone to deviations from theoretical distributions?

Tags: distributions

From the time I started the study of statistics I have noticed that the tails of distributions from samples are usually the ones that deviate from theoretical distributions.

For example, most Q-Q plots fail to fit the y=x line around the start and end points.

What is the reason for this and what are some of the techniques used to address this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a general answer that applies in all cases, but I think one big factor is that deviations are more noticeable in the tails.

Suppose that you suspect that the variable in question should be normally distributed.  For concreteness, let's say it's height of adult human males. Now, in some reasonable sized sample (say N = 100) the Normal might predict a single person who  is over 6'3".  But if there are none, or two, that will be very apparent.  On the other hand it might predict 10 people between 5'9 and 5'10".  If there are 9, or 11, that won't be so apparent.

It may also be that the *actual* distribution is not exactly normal.  But, again, deviations will be more apparent in the tails.

```
set.seed(1234)  #Sets a random number seed

dist1 <- rnorm(100,0, 1) #Random normal with N = 100, mean 0, sd 1
dist2 <- c(dist1, 4) #Add a single extreme point
dist3 <- c(dist1, 0) #Add a point at the mean

qqplot(dist1,dist2)
qqplot(dist1, dist3)
```